# Toggling variables from for loop in python and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, tkinter, lambda

I'm new with python and stack overflow so sorry if this question is below average. Anyway, I'm trying to make a Registration Software with python and tkinter, and I want to make it so that the buttons toggle between the purple colour: *#ff4dd2*. It is made hard because the buttons are created from a loop, I can't assign a variable to the buttons. If you could take the time to take a look at this it would be really appreciated   **:)** (The current code works as expected, hopefully you can understand what I mean)

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime
import re

root = Tk()
root.title("Attendence Register")
root.geometry('1350x650+0+0')

root.resizable(False, False)

nameframe = Frame(root, height=650, width=300)
nameframe.pack(side='left')

saveframe = Frame(root, height=650, width=300)
saveframe.pack(side='right')

outlist = []

def saveDataPresent(line):
    present[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
    line = (line + ' is present')
    outlist.append(line)
    #print(outlist)

def saveDataAbsent(line):
    absent[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
    line = (line + ' is absent')
    outlist.append(line)
    #print(outlist)

def saveDataIll(line):
    ill[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
    line = (line + ' is ill')
    outlist.append(line)
    #print(outlist)

def saveDataHoliday(line):
    holiday[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
    line = (line + ' is on holiday')
    outlist.append(line)
    #print(outlist)

def saveData():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now = str(now)
    dire = 'logs/'
    now = dire + now

    now = re.sub(':', '', now)
    now += '.txt'

    log = open(now, "w+")
    log.close()
    log = open(now, "a")
    for i in outlist:
        i = (i + '\n')
        log.write(i)
    log.close()

text = open('names.txt','r')
line = text.readline()
count = 0
present = {}
absent = {}
ill = {}
holiday = {}

for line in text:
    count+= 1
    name = Label(nameframe, text=line)
    name.grid(row=count, column = 0)


    present[line] =  Button(nameframe, text='/', pady = 20, padx=20, bg ='#66ff66', command=lambda line=line: saveDataPresent(line))
    present[line].grid(row=count, column = 2)

    holiday[line] = Button(nameframe, text='H', pady=20, padx=20, bg='light blue', command=lambda line=line: saveDataHoliday(line))
    holiday[line].grid(row=count, column=3)

    ill[line] = Button(nameframe, text='ill', pady=20, padx=20, bg ='#ffa31a', command=lambda line=line: saveDataIll(line))
    ill[line].grid(row=count, column=4)

    absent[line] = Button(nameframe, text='NA', pady=20, padx=20, bg ='#ff6666', command=lambda line=line: saveDataAbsent(line))
    absent[line].grid(row=count, column=5)

savebut = Button(saveframe, text='Save', pady = 20, padx=20, command=saveData)
savebut.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The buttons are put into the dictionaries above the loop. Can't you just get the buttons from the dictionary its in?

Comment: Please add some more context to your question. I am not 100% sure what it is you need. The buttons do turn purple. Are you wanting them to change back?

Comment: Thanks for your input, thanks to you I've managed to solve the issue. I didn't use the dictionary the buttons were in. but i made a new dictionary for each button, which i then linked to the line, and that worked: `def saveDataHoliday(line):
    holidaycount[line] += 1

    if holidaycount[line] % 2 == 1:
        holiday[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
        line = (line + ' is holiday')
        outlist.append(line)
        #print(outlist)

    else:
        holiday[line].configure(bg='light blue')
        line = (line + ' is holiday')
        outlist.remove(line)`

Comment: Thanks mike for trying to help, and sorry for the lack of context. I haave posted the solution so hopefully that should clear up any confusion you had about my question. I basically wanted them to toggle between going purple and the button color, and when the button was purple it would append something to a list, and it would remove that when it wasn't purple

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the comments but it didnt look nice:

```
def saveDataHoliday(line):
holidaycount[line] += 1

if holidaycount[line] % 2 == 1:
    holiday[line].configure(bg='#ff4dd2')
    line = (line + ' is holiday')
    outlist.append(line)
    #print(outlist)

else:
    holiday[line].configure(bg='light blue')
    line = (line + ' is holiday')
    outlist.remove(line)
    #print(outlist)enter code here
```

holidaycount was defined earlier as a dictionary:

```
holidaycount = {}
```

I did this for each button(absent, present etc) Then after that:

```
for line in text:
count+= 1
name = Label(nameframe, text=line)
name.grid(row=count, column = 0)

presentcount[line] = 0
absentcount[line] = 0
illcount[line] = 0
holidaycount[line] = 0
```